# Assign data from LocalStorage to a block of data (Angular2)

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

So, I used data declared by myself, but now i switch the code to LocalStorage, and I'd like to know, how to get the data from one element of LocalStorage, and insert it to a block of data from my program.

Here's a part of code which shows the procedure which i use for inserting data

```
let l = this.lists;
localStorage.setItem('lists', JSON.stringify(l));
```

l is of type string, and lists is an array with data block.

I wanted to use this command

```
this.lists = localStorage.getItem('lists');
```

but unfortunately,it wants a string element, and doesn't want to work with my lists element...

> Info time:
>
> LocalStorage is implementation of Storage interface and it accepts and
>   returns plain strings so every time you want to store there something
>   a little bit more complex you have to serialize when inserting
>   (`JSON.stringify`) and deserialize when retrieving (`JSON.parse`)

Comment: `this.lists =JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('lists'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

> The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.

```
this.lists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lists'));
```

`localStorage` is implementation of [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) interface, It works on plain strings. When you want to work with complex object serialize it using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and deserialize using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)